# wpa_supplicant.conf for android hotspot

Tags: wifi, wireless

I've the following working wpa_supplicant.conf to connect my raspberry pi b+ 3.18.12+ to the wifi:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={  
  ssid="my_wifi_ssid"  
  psk="my_wifi_psk"  
  proto=WPA  
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
  pairwise=TKIP  
  auth_alg=OPEN  
}
```

Now, I'm trying to configure my raspberry to connect it to an Android hotspot. I believed that the same configuration will works for an Android hotspot but it's not the case.

I then tried a simpler configuration knowing that in most cases wpa_supplicant choose the best configuration:

```
network={ 
  ssid="my_hotspot_ssid"  
  psk="my_hotspot_psk"  
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK #I've also tried without this line
}
```

But nothing works. How can I connect my pi connect to an Android hotspot ?

I don't know if it can help but I've tried these configurations with a Samsung galaxy grand Android 4.4.4 and an Iphone 6. Moreover, this is the content of my `/etc/network/interfaces` files:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: The accepted solution worked for me, but first I had to switch my hotspot network to 2.4GHz instead of 5GHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I've found the good configuration for my Android 4.4.4:

```
network={
  ssid="my_ssid"
  psk="my_passwd"
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP
  auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

It also works for an Iphone 6.

Answer (score 2):

The answer's settings worked for me, but I would like to add a simple (incredibly frustrating) alternative: check for a space at the end of your phone's Hotspot name. On a lot of phones, your keyboard (which may be custom, like Swiftkey or Swype) will automatically add a space at the end of a word. This is a totally valid SSID: `"hotspot"` and `"hotspot "` are different things.

However, if you run: `iwlist scan > network.txt`, have a look at the ESSIDs that show up. In my case I saw `"Myhotspot "`.

You won't notice this on almost any other platform because typically you select the name in a graphical menu and the trailing space will be invisible.